# failed to use moment to format date in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
<p> Last update: {moment({obj.updated_at}).format('DD MMM YYY')}</p>
```

I'm expecting this output : 30 Mar 2017 but I got error of unexpected of token error?

Comment: Why the brackets around `{obj.updated_at}`?

Comment: this is not valid javascript syntax for es5 or es6: `{obj.updated_at}`

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to -

```
<p> Last update: {moment(obj.updated_at).format('DD MMM YYY')}</p>
```

**What's wrong with the original code?**

In JSX, the `<p></p>` syntax gets converted into a `React.createElement` call, with the code inside `{}` blocks being converted into the parameters of the call. A nested `{}` block is invalid in this case because it cannot be transpiled into valid parameter value chain. You only ever need one level of `{}` blocks within a JSX tag.

You can test this easily on [Babel-Repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=%3Cp%3E%20Last%20update%3A%20%7Bmoment(obj.updated_at).format(%27DD%20MMM%20YYY%27)%7D%3C%2Fp%3E).